# How could the government allow schools to run Captain America videos?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, we saw Peter's school running Captain America videos to motivate students.

How could the U.S. government allow this?

In *Captain America: Civil War*, Captain America turned out to be an outlaw and fugitive.

Answer (score 20):

The Teacher actually makes the statement something like.

"Although he is a war criminal or something, but we have the videos here so better watch them."

Given the events of Civil war had only taken place a few months previously and the time it takes government to act. Plus the fact that Someone no doubt paid a lot of money for these videos I imagine it would be several years before they where phased out of the Curriculum.

Comment: Personally thought this was a magnificent touch of realism to the film; most schools I've known have equipment and videos that are years out of date- they've paid good money for these motivational videos and they're not going to throw them away just because of some altercation! Who knows when they'd find something to replace them?

Comment: I believe the gym teacher says that the state is still **requiring** that they show the videos, despite CA being a war criminal. So it's less, "We have them so we might as well use them" and more, "If we don't show these videos we'll get in trouble."

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd that sounds a closer version of what he said, only seen it once so far hoping to go see it at least once more in cinema so will try and get the line exactly when I do :).

Comment: Hah. We had to watch anti drug videos that were so out of date they warned about a future where breath-analysis vans may one day be used by police to determine blood alcohol content in as little as 3 hours. Showing a van with a lab and 3 techs working away in it. The same video also said "while generally considered safe, new evidence shows cocaine may be addictive". Schools don't update those videos often at all, it's more unbelievable they would be recent enough to have the captain at all.